# Angular Leaflet MarkerCluster from geojson

Tags: angularjs, geojson, markerclusterer, angular-leaflet-directive

I want to show the leaflet MarkerCluster on the map, and the problem is at retrieving data from GeoJSON:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": 
    [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "sto",
            "properties": {
                "name": "Stoke"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                   -0.0731,
                   51.5615
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "dal",
            "properties": {
                "name": "Dalston"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -0.070,
                    51.545
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "wan",
            "properties": {
                "name": "Wandsworth"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -0.1924,
                    51.4644
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "batt",
            "properties": {
                "name": "Battersea"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -0.1677,
                    51.4638
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to reproduce the same situation in in two examples:

1. [Working MarkerCluster, but without geojson data](http://jsfiddle.net/ocLrg71c/)
2. [Second with geojson, but MarkerCluster doesn't work](http://plnkr.co/edit/wIRItne2gBNPevKQ0pOh?p=preview)

Does anybody knows why MarkerCluster in the second example does not show?
Did I miss some attribute in geojson?

Comment: they both show the same thing on my end ..

Comment: But at the beginning unfortunately is not the case [Example with geojson](http://i.imgur.com/JkMKDEm.png) [Example without geojson](http://i.imgur.com/1yJ6aMY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this (discussion and code snippets [here](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/issues/744))

```
// Get the countries geojson data from a JSON
$http.get("test.geojson").success(function(data, status) {
    addGeoJsonLayerWithClustering(data);

    function addGeoJsonLayerWithClustering(data) {
        var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
        var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Nome.value);
            }
        });
        markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
        leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
            map.addLayer(markers);
            map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());
        });
    }

});
```